# How to include ui.router in AngularJS project?

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, angular-ui-router, bower

I keep getting this error:

`Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.router' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.

But I am pretty sure I have everything configured correctly

The project was created with Yeoman and uses Bower to manage dependencies, with Grunt to build everything.

The yeoman angular generator created the boilerplate with the basic ngRouter, so I installed ui.router with

```
bower install angular-ui-router --save
```

**Angular Version**

```
1.2.16
```

**Bower file**

The above line updated the bower.json file with this line in the dependencies list:

```
"angular-ui-router": "~0.2.10"
```

**app Module set up**

I updated the *app.js* file with by adding the dependency on *ui.route* (in addition to various other dependencies)
    angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', ... 'ui.router'])

**index.html**

```
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
...
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

I have the above file in the above directory, I am positive it is there (I copied and pasted the path to avoid typos).  I also tried the minified version with no difference.

**EDIT**

I am very, *very* new to all of this (angular, bower, yeoman, etc) So I may very well be doing this all wrong, so could it be that I no longer need to include the ui.router dependency? I mean, has it been integrated to the *core* angular framework somehow?  Is ui.router deprecated?

Comment: I would assume that the order of your includes is off. Maybe your script tag for ui-router comes after you've included the script that has your `angular.module` call. There's a minimal example of the setup available at http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router

Comment: Nope, I added the **ui-router** reference before my main _app.js_ (which contains the `anugular.module` stuff)

Comment: Is `angular-ui-router.js` loaded correctly? Anything in the devtools?

Comment: Should be.  Just to make sure, I tried loading the script directly from the following URL and still getting the same error: `<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>`

Answer (score 5):

I'm dumb.  Found the answer from [this link](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth/issues/52). When running `grunt` on the cmd line, it is configured to not only build and check for errors, but run tests as well (using karma which I do not understand yet).

So what needed to change was the karma config file:

`<project root>/test/karma.conf.js`

Below, the indented line was what I needed to add:

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
      'bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
      'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
      'bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',
         'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
      'app/scripts/**/*.js',
      'test/mock/**/*.js',
      'test/spec/**/*.js'
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through with this link, you will get complete structure to work with angular.js using ui router

[Github Repository](https://github.com/pandeysoni/Angular-UI-Router-Boilerplate)